# How to Pass the Controller Data to JS File in CakePHP 3.0

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

In CakePHP 2.0, I've used the link below to pass controller data to a js file. However, I can longer use this method anymore as CakePHP 3.0 has removed js helper.

Is there a new technique for me to pass the controller data to a js file or alternative method beside using js helper with the link below?

http://www.php-dev-zone.com/2014/01/how-to-pass-controller-data-to-js-file.html

Relevant code:

```
public function beforeRender()
{
    // We are Setting the jsvariables array which holds the
    // variables that will be used in js files.
    $this->set('jsVars', $this->_jsvariables);
}
```

```
<?php echo $this->Html->scriptBlock('var jsVars = '.$this->Js->object($jsVars).';'); ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just check what the `JsHelper::object()` method was doing, and then do it manually.

**[https://github.com/cakephp/.../2.7.0/lib/Cake/View/Helper/JsBaseEngineHelper.php#L127](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.7.0/lib/Cake/View/Helper/JsBaseEngineHelper.php#L127)**

It's basically just a call to `json_encode()`, so simply replace the helper method call accordingly:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->scriptBlock('var jsVars = ' . json_encode($jsVars) . ';'); ?>
```